# Select and Insert in node loop not working as expected

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am trying to insert data in table before checking that Is it already exist in database table? If exist then loop continue with console message "Already exist" and If not exist then I try to insert in table. But some of the records are already in database table then also Inserted in table.

**Following My NodeJS Code**

```
(function loop(index){
            if(index==apires.items.length){     
                console.log("Cron completed");              
                res.send("Cron completed");
                return false;
            }
            inventoryObj = apires.items[index];
            hash_name = inventoryObj.market_hash_name;

            db.query('SELECT market_hash_name FROM inventory_master WHERE market_hash_name = "'+hash_name+'"', function(err,result, fields){
                if(result.length){
                    console.log('already exist');
                    loop(++index);
                }
                else
                {
                    var post  = {data_here};
                    var query = db.query('INSERT INTO inventory_master SET ?', post, function (error, results, fields) {
                    if (error) throw error;           
                        loop(++index);
                    });
                }   
            });     
        })(0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is happening due to the asynchronous behavior of your code. You can use `async` library to make it working, this will allow your code to execute on element at a time. Example

```
// assuming apires.itemsis an array 
async.each(apires.items, function(inventoryObj, callback) {

            hash_name = inventoryObj.market_hash_name;

            db.query('SELECT market_hash_name FROM inventory_master WHERE market_hash_name = "'+hash_name+'"', function(err,result, fields){
                if(result.length){
                    console.log('already exist');
                    callback('success'); // go for next iteration
                }
                else
                {
                    var post  = {data_here};
                    var query = db.query('INSERT INTO inventory_master SET ?', post, function (error, results, fields) {
                    if (error) throw error;           
                        callback('success'); // go for next iteration
                    });
                }   
            });     
}, function(err) {
   //once all finished, it will come here,if no error occurred then err will be null
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try it. Can you tell me where I am wrong in my code Just for my information I am asking.

Comment: Whenever there is a input output operation happens in node js then thread do not wait for I/O operation to complete and it will go to next iteration of your loop. So there is not clear sequence of execution of your code. This async method will make sure that you your all the records are processed in the same sequence.

Comment: I am used callback function as per nodejs rules and syntax. Can you point out where actually my code wrong?

Comment: Oh Man i got it, sorry about that. I did not notice that. Now one thing i can think of is your database object. It may be possible that it is not synchronized. Other then this i dont see any problem in your code, it looks awesome.

Comment: Now can you tell me where I wrong? I have little bit confusion about I/O operation and Blocking/Non Blocking code.

Comment: Thank you for your code. It working perfect dear. Dont know what issue in my given code but your code working like charm!!!